# Cannot make transparent background anymore Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]This is a weird problem. Trying to create a new document with a transparent background, but transparent background is not showing up in the menu any longer.

Was it in a parallel universe I used to have an option to create a document with a transparent background? In my parallel universe transparent background worked yesterday.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to click on Advanced Options, just **scroll down**.

When you click on the drop down, to show the background options, they get pushed downwards, off screen and behind the Close/Create buttons.  Clicking on Advanced Options does the same thing, pushing the screen down, but with an unnecessary step.

This seems like a bit of an oversight by Adobe's design team, so hopefully they fix this in a future update.

[image]

Comment: Wow what a design fail from Adobe's side... For me the scrollbar doesn't even appear like in your screen but I can indeed scroll down. Thanks for adding!

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'Advanced options' underneath the background contents for the option 'Transparent' to become available.

[image]

I never use this option so I can't tell you if it was in the main dropdown or not but it would make more sense if it was.

Comment: This is complete nonsence in terms of usability. The `Advanced` should be a switch not a menu.

Comment: Totally agree, it doesn't make sense.